# Getting the scrollbottom using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which gets the amount the user has scrolled from the top and the bottom and then using these values it should hide or show the shadows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(window).height() ) {
        $('div.shadow-bottom').show();
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 15 ) {
            $('div.shadow-top').show();
        } else {
            $('div.shadow-top').hide();
        }
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(window).height() - 15 ) {
            $('div.shadow-bottom').show();
        } else {
            $('div.shadow-bottom').hide();
        }

    });

});
```

The top works fine, but the bottom one should be hiding when you get to the bottom of the page BUT then show again if you are 15 pixels from the bottom.

Example: http://dev.driz.co.uk/shadow/

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can post html and css. :)

Comment: Added example to original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport

$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document

Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 15) {
    $('div.shadow-bottom').show();
 }

 $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 15) {
        $('div.shadow-top').show();
    } else {
        $('div.shadow-top').hide();
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 15) {
        $('div.shadow-bottom').show();
    } else {
        $('div.shadow-bottom').hide();
    }

 });

});​
```

Comment: Almost. But the shadow is showing when I reach the bottom instead of showing when NOT at the bottom and then hiding once the bottom is reached! BUT should only show if needed e.g. the page is big enough. I've posted the answer above but I'll give you the accept.

Answer (score 1):

The correct working example is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

             if ($(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $('div.shadow-bottom').show();
             }

             $(window).scroll(function() {

                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 15) {
                    $('div.shadow-top').show();
                } else {
                    $('div.shadow-top').hide();
                }
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 15) {
                    $('div.shadow-bottom').hide();
                } else {
                    $('div.shadow-bottom').show();
                }

             });

            });
```

Which is based on bhb's answer above.